# Remove remote branch from a Jenkins job

Tags: git, powershell, jenkins, tfs

I have a maintenance job in **Jenkins** for my **Git** repository (**git on TFS online**) to remove branches that don't match specific conditions or stale branches. When running the job it says this:

```
Going to remove branch development/Batch_R7
fatal: InvalidOperationException encountered.
   Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in 
UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification 
or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service 
application.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://everisidbtfs.visualstudio.com': No 
error
```

I run this command from a **Powershell** script.

Other Git commands work fine in that Powershell script, for example to get a list of branches.

If I run the PowerShell script from the Powershell command line in the Jenkins server (or in any other machine) it works fine.

The TFS user has permissions to remove remotes and credentials are provided to the Jenkins job.

This is the Git command I use to remove branches:

```
git push --porcelain --progress --recurse-submodules=check origin :refs/heads/<branch_name>
```

Is there any workaround for this? What am I doing wrong?

It comes to my mind that, since the git command is a "write" operation (a push), maybe there's some security limitation in Jenkins to do that... The rest of the git commands I use in automation scripts are "readonly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It comes to my mind that, since the git command is a "write" operation (a push), maybe there's some security limitation in Jenkins to do that...

Exactly: all other operations are local to the repo, except the push one, which will require authentication. You need to make sure the account executing the script in Jenkins has the proper credentials. If the https URL used has no authentication information in it, that means it should rely to

- either a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)
- or, specific to Jenkins, a [Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)

Comment: Hum... I have the Windows Credential Store installed and the Credential Plugin, but since Jenkins is running using the SYSTEM account (since it by default runs as a windows service) I think that the issue is related to that... the credentials are stored for my windows admin user. I'll take a look into it and let you know! I would like to avoid messing up with the SYSTEM user if possible :) Many thanks!!!

Comment: Starting the Jenkins service as a regular user with my credentials stored worked fine.